# Tracking modified state with NSTextStorage and UNDO

Tags: macos, nstextview, undo, nstextstorage

I have an NSTextView/NSTextStorage combination and I want to track the 'modified' state of the text storage.

I could simply watch for changes to the text and update my 'modifiedDate' variable - problem is I need UNDO to work also - and UNDO should also undo the modifiedDate.

If I update my modifiedDate variable each time the text changes then it works - but UNDO on the TextView will be one character at a time (not desirable.)

I did try looking for undoManagerWillCloseUndoGroupNotification and updating my modifiedDate there, but I get the same effect (single character undo) I thought it might 'slip' the modifiedDate undo inside the TextView undo group - but it appears not.

This is either one of those things that just can't be done - or it's simple - can someone put me out of my misery?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The 'solution' is to log my modifiedDate when receiving undoManagerDidOpenUndoGroupNotification (and first responder is my NSTextView)

Other thing to watch for is drag/drop onto NSTextView (when it isn't first responder) - in that case I found that setting first responder to my NSTextView in the readSelectionFromPasteboard: override on my NSTextView sorted things.